# Closure of the complement of a subset in a topological space

Tags: general-topology, self-learning

I am trying to get a quick introduction on topology in order to study measure theory. Nevertheless, I am at a halt since I cannot really validate this proposition:

[image]

Shouldn't the complement of an open set contained in A be every set that is either closed or not contained in A, so not necessarily those which are both closed and containing the contrary of A?

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mistaking complement at two different levels.

Consider a family

$$\mathcal{A} = \{ U \subseteq X : U \subseteq A \ \& \ U \text{ is open } \}$$

1. The complement of this family (in $\mathcal{P}(X)$) is

   $$\mathcal{A}^c = \{ U \subseteq X : U \not \subseteq A \text{ or } U \text{ is not open }\}.$$

   It is the set of those $U$ which do not belong to $\mathcal{A}$.
2. The set of complements of sets in this family is

   $$\{ U^c : U \in \mathcal{A} \} = \{ F \subseteq X : F \supseteq X \setminus A \ \& \ F \text{ is closed } \}.$$

   It is the set of those $F$ whose complement $F^c$ belong to $\mathcal{A}$.

Those are two different notions. You're thinking of the first while the proof goes with the second:

$$\bigcap_{U \in \mathcal{A}} (X \setminus U) = \bigcap \{ U^c : U \in \mathcal{A} \} = \bigcap \{ F \subseteq X : F \supseteq X \setminus A \ \& \ F \text{ is closed } \}.$$

Comment: Also note that in the first case the statement _$U$ is not open_ is NOT equivalent to _$U$ is closed_, which is a similar mistake of putting the complement on a wrong level: $$\mathcal{G} = \{ G \subseteq X : G \text{ is open} \} \\[1ex] \{ F \subseteq X : F \text{ is closed} \} = \{ G^c : G \in \mathcal{G} \} \color{red}{\neq} \mathcal{G}^c.$$ Closed sets are complements of open sets, but the family of closed sets is NOT the complement of the family of open sets.

Comment: Exactly, thank you very much! This was the explanation I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The complement of a set $A$ which is a subset of a set $X$ is$$X\setminus A=\{x\in X\,|\,x\notin A\}.$$So, the complement of an open set $O$ contained in $A$ is a closed set (since it is the complement of an open one) containing $X\setminus A$.

Comment: Sorry if I did not make myself clear caro professor. My doubt was in the third step: X\U if U is open and is contained in A necessarily needs to be closed and containing X\A?

Comment: @RAGMS Yes. $U$ open $\implies X\setminus U$ closed, and $U\subseteq A\implies X\setminus A\subseteq X\setminus U$.

Comment: @drhab my problem is not with the complements of each specification my problem is with the intersection. If I understand correctly "," is equivalent to the operator AND, thus, the complement should be a reunion. So let's say a set is both contained in A and open, it's complement are sets which are either not open or containing the  complement of A, so not necessarily closed AND containing the complement. I know that my reasoning is wrong but this is what makes sense to me.

Comment: @RAGMS "it's complement **are** sets..." No, in this context every set $U$ has only **one** set as complement, which is the set $X\setminus U$. In the proof every $X\setminus U$ in the intersection simply gets a new name $F$ and the properties of $U$ (open subset of $A$) are translated to properties of $F=X\setminus U$ (closed superset of $X\setminus A$).

Answer (score 0):

You could also reason like this.

$\mathring A$ is the *largest* open subset of $A$ in the sense that it contains every open subset of $A$.

Then **automatically** $X\setminus\mathring A$ is the *smallest* closed superset of $X\setminus A$ in the sense that it is contained in every closed superset of $X\setminus A$.

This states exactly that $X\setminus\mathring A$ is the closure of $X\setminus A$.